# Conditional comments for CSS class on html tag in Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am a beginner in web development and I need help from other experienced web developers. For compatibility issues with IE, I came across Paul Irish's Conditional comments but I am very green to it. Where does the code below go, after ***doctype html*** or in the ***head*** tag?

```html
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class=""><!--<[endif]-->
```

And what exactly is the code in those classes supposed to be with an example please.

Comment: *..but I am very green to it..* and the image is very *blue* ;)

Comment: For future reference the {} symbol in the editor allows you to add code blocks to your question, which means that people answering your question can copy/paste your code if necessary (which here, it kind of is) - Much more efficient than using an image to show your code!

Comment: just to add on to the answers below. Do not use conditional comments, they are now deprecated. You really need to leverage feature detection, etc.

Comment: @ChrisLove how do I do that? Is there a javascript code for that?

Comment: @ChrisLove so I use modernizr?

Comment: Sorry for not providing a reference, here is a Gist showing how I detect to redirect to a core site: https://gist.github.com/docluv/51ad2e57fc8a50997ee1. You can see the full example application: https://github.com/docluv/movies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment block is designed go in place of the `html` tag, so *after* the `doctype` declaration.

### However...

With that in mind- I would tend to **urge you to not target IE** or worse still, specific versions of IE in your CSS.

You should always strive to create a layout, (HTML and styles) which is(are) cross browser compatible, supporting [**progressive enhancement**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [**graceful degradation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system). I appreciate this is not always terribly easy, but in increasingly complex sites it is a far better approach than attempting to *specifically* cater for differing versions of different browsers, instead of learning how to implement CSS/featuresets supported by all.

In the long run, especially if you are *learning* CSS- you will inevitably experience initial frustration but you will learn *a lot more* by not using conditional comments.

As noted in the comments on this answer, conditional comments are basically *accepting* you are, or will be, introducing error, and coding around it - the point is **you should never accept you are introducing error** in the first place but code to prevent it from arising at all. You should implement fault tolerance in your CSS by using styles and properties which gracefully degrade.

Comment: My question to you SW4 on Progressive Enhancement would be, do you have a website that I can learn from(especially HTML, CSS and JavaScript) that incorporate the principles of Progressive Enhancement?

Comment: @Ng'esh - not one I use, but the top result from google looks like a decent intro: http://alistapart.com/article/progressiveenhancementwithcss, just google 'CSS progressive enhancement'

Comment: And about Fault Tolerance, I understood that HTML is designed to be forward compatible, allowing new HTML entities to be ignored by Web browsers which do not understand them without causing the document to be unusable. Doesn't that suggest we go with Conditional Comments which you are of the suggestion of not using conditional comments. I would like for you to expound on your last statement.

Comment: Thanks for that link. At least we are heading somewhere. I found from the same site one for JavaScript: http://alistapart.com/article/progressiveenhancementwithjavascript

Comment: @Ng'esh regarding fault tolerance, conditional comments are basically accepting you are introducing error, and coding around it - the point is you should never *accept* you are introducing error in the first place but code to prevent it from arising at all. You should implement fault tolerance in your CSS by using styles and properties which gracefully degrade

Comment: Makes sense about Fault tolerance. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Ohw, thanks. So I should know how certain devices how they display the websites am constructing individually?

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted would go just under the doctype declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
// THE CODE HERE
```

The class names are given so that CSS can be applied to certain versions of IE since not all CSS works in every version of IE.

For example you could set an element to have a fixed height only in IE8

```
html.ie8 #someElement {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Another way to explain the positioning (not worth own answer): where you would normally have the `<html>` tag, since these are just adding classes to that tag. If you don't have an `<html>` tag in your current page, it's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

THAT code in particular goes after the `DOCTYPE` tag as it is a conditional replacement for the `<html>` opening tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6"><!endif>-->
...etc.
<head>...</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

The classes (ie6, ie7, ie8, etc.) are meant to contain styling to address styling inconsistencies across browsers.

In this respect, you might want to look at [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and [Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) which aim to make your life a bit easier in terms of cross browser rendering.

Comment: But do you have to edit the css files to suit the design of the website one is creating?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your html-tag with this, so it goes below the doctype. It sets different classes in the html-tag that you can use both in CSS and JavaScript, if you want to set special styling for a certain browser, or if you want to include fallback-scripts for older versions of IE.

Comment: Can you h=give me an example of a fallback-script apart from css?

Comment: Lets say you want an element to fade in or out, and you use CSS3 transitions to do it. That doesn't work in IE below version 9, so you could add a script fallback in those cases, maybe like this: `if($('html').hasClass('ie8')){ $(element).fadeIn(); }`

Answer (score -1):

I came across this site [Better conditional classnames for hack-free CSS](http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-conditional-classnames-for-hack-free-css/)

which explains other different ways of using the conditional comments.

It has descsribed three ways of applying conditional comments:

1. The “bubble up” conditional comments method
2. The “preemptive” conditional comments method
3. The “bubble up” conditional comments method without including the conditional comments in the head of the document.

And for more information on different platforms for using the Conditional Comments go to this site http://conditionalcomment.com which has the various codes you seek.

PHP can go anywhere. If you want to use it for browser detection and alternate CSS, place it in the head. And, use it just like any other PHP string in the body. If you check for many different browsers, browser versions, or OSes, then you might want to make it a file and include the file in the head. Just go to you will get the code: [killersites](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/2361-firefox-google-chrome-browser-detecion-using-conditional-comments-hack/)